# How to get my params value with a &amp; in the URL?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, parameters, code-behind, asp.net-webpages

```
www.myurl.com?param1=123&param2=456 OK
www.myurl.com?param1=123&amp;param2=456 NOT OK
```

In my vb code behind, with the second URL, I get the value of param1 only.

```
Me.Page.Request("param1") : value OK
Me.Page.Request("param2") : value 0
```

Comment: Please can you explain why you need to use &amp; in the querystring?

Comment: In the second URL, the second key is `amp;param2`. Dont use HTML entities in your URL; use percent encoding for the latter.

Comment: I send the URL to customers with & but some of them get &amp; instead. And I don't know what to do about that as it's on client side.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would advise rethinking how your URL is built with a view to removing the need for an `&amp`; it will be far easier for you.

If this is not possible for whatever reason, you will need to extract the parameter values from the querystring yourself.

One possible solution:

```
    Dim url As String = Request.RawUrl
    Dim urlParams As String() = url.Split("?"C)

    If urlParams.Length > 1 Then
       Dim parameters As String() = urlParams(1).Split(New String() {"&amp;"}, StringSplitOptions.None)

       For Each param As var In parameters
          ' will give you the paramater value
          Dim value As String = param.Split("="C)(1)
       Next
    End If
```

Comment: The `&` from `&amp;` is not included in the key; it is seen as separator.